# lua '=' expected near 'G1'

Tags: lua, router, putty, openwrt, linksys

Was following this guide: http://blog.jgc.org/2012/03/ambient-bus-arrival-monitor-from-hacked.html

Im currently stuck on this bit "The program has three parameters: a comma separated list of bus routes, a bus stop number and a 'walking time'. For example, it's possible to do:
lua ambibus.lua 3,12 50906 2"

The bus that runs near my house is the "G1" and whenever i try to add it in PuTTy is says  '=' expected near 'G1'

If i copy and paste the code in the instructions i get "lua: cannot open ambibus.lua: No such file or directory"

Help please

Comment: To be able to help, we will likely need to see the code your are trying to write/use. What exactly are you entering into putty? `ambibus.lua` is a Lua script file. Is it supposed to exist as part of the application you are trying to use? Or was that just an example?

Comment: Im trying to use winscp to put those lua files on the serial port by just copying them in. I've tried changing the perms of the file using "sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/" but it returns it to default after reboot. I need those files on the serial port folder to be able to display to a LCD screen.